# How to find the last Occurence of an element in a Queue in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to find the last occurence of a particular string in a 
queue.I am using another queues and variables. I am stuck here though, should i use stacks or queues to solve this and how.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class StackQueue{
public static void remove(Queue<String> queue, String toRemove){
    if(queue.isEmpty()){throw new NullPointerException();}

    Queue<String> tmp = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<String> tmp1 = new LinkedList<>();
    int count = 0;

    while(! queue.isEmpty()){
        String removed = queue.remove();        
        if(toRemove == removed){
            tmp.add(removed);
            count++;
        }
        else{
            tmp1.add(removed);
        }       
    }

    while (!tmp1.isEmpty()){
        queue.add(tmp1.remove());
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add("a");
    q.add("e");
    q.add("b");
    q.add("a");     
    q.add("e");


    System.out.println(q);
    remove(q, "a");     
    System.out.println(q);
}
 }
```

Comment: What does *last occurrence* mean to you?  Index?

Comment: @JacobG. What else would indicate a last element in a list-based structure?

Comment: @AKSW only that `Queue`s are no `List`s. Only thing they got in common is that they are both `Collection`s.

Comment: @DSlomer64, if you would like to critique a post, please use comments instead of modifying the question to add in your reviews.

Comment: @BhargavRao--as I recall, I couldn't find what seemed a suitable place to stick my comment and so, as I recall, I wrote a note like "EDITED" and put my revised edit there. As I recall, I put a lot of effort into it. Can you send me what I put in? I'm new at reviewing and sometimes it isn't clear whether I'm reviewing the current not-yet-approved edit or the original Question or where to put my words. Is there somewhere I can go to get a better feel for it all?

Answer (score 2):

A `Queue` isn't a good fit for your usage, in fact the name of your class `StackQueue` hints that you probably want a `Deque` (although this may be coincidence).

The `Deque` (double-ended queue) interface specifies the exact method you require, [`removeLastOccurrence(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#removeLastOccurrence-java.lang.Object-). Essentially a `Deque` lets you add a remove from both ends, which also facilitates `Stack` behavior and so if a lot more flexible, giving you remove operations which work from both ends.

A `Queue` in contrast only provides removal from the front of the queue or by searching for first occurrence found in the `Queue` (although this can be implementation dependent since the [`remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) method specified in the `Collection` interface does not state that it has to be the first occurrence...)

The issue with a `Queue` for your use case is that the interface is intended to only allow queue like behavior, preventing usage of the underlying implementation without casting which would allow such a task to be performed more easily (e.g. `LinkedList` or `ArrayDeque`). Casting is far from desirable for this, what if the actual implementation changed?

If you insist on using a `Queue` then another solution which does not requiring making another `Queue` would be to use the queue's `Iterator` and `Iterator.remove()`. For example:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class QueueExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add("a");
        queue.add("b");
        queue.add("c");
        queue.add("a");
        queue.add("d");
        queue.add("a");
        queue.add("b");
        System.out.println("Before: " + queue);
        remove(queue, "a");
        System.out.println("After: " + queue);
    }

    public static void remove(Queue<String> queue, String toRemove){
        int indexToRemove = findLastIndex(queue, toRemove);
        removeIndex(queue, indexToRemove);
    }

    private static int findLastIndex(Queue<String> queue, String value) {
        int indexToRemove = -1;
        int index = 0;
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = queue.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); index++) {
            String current = iterator.next();
            if (value.equals(current)) {
                indexToRemove = index;
            }
        }
        return indexToRemove;
    }

    private static void removeIndex(Queue<String> queue, int indexToRemove) {
        int index = 0;
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = queue.iterator(); iterator.hasNext() && index <= indexToRemove; index++) {
            iterator.next();
            if (index == indexToRemove) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. Iterate through the queue and dump its contents into a temporary queue (like you're doing). Keep track of the last seen index of the element to remove. Lastly, iterate through the temporary queue and dump its contents back into the original queue, ignoring the item at the found index.

```
public static void remove(Queue<String> queue, String toRemove) {
    Queue<String> tmp = new LinkedList<>();
    int lastFoundIdx = -1;

    for (int i = 0; !queue.isEmpty(); i++) {
        String elem = queue.poll();

        if (elem.equals(toRemove)) {
            lastFoundIdx = i;
        }

        tmp.offer(elem);
    }

    for (int i = 0; !tmp.isEmpty(); i++) {
        if (i == lastFoundIdx) {
            tmp.poll();
        }
        else {
            queue.offer(tmp.poll());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not agree more to d.j.brown, stack is the best fit for your case. In fact there is a built in function that returns lastIndexOf an element of a stack. Below is the working example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.add("a");
    stack.add("e");
    stack.add("b");
    stack.add("k");
    stack.add("b");
    stack.add("c");
    stack.add("l");

    System.out.println("Original stack: " + stack);
    remove(stack, "a");
    System.out.println("Modified stack: " + stack);
  }

  private static void remove(Stack<String> stack, String toRemove) {
    int indexOfToRemove = stack.lastIndexOf(toRemove);
    if (indexOfToRemove == -1) {
      return;
    }
    Stack<String> tempStack = new Stack<>();
    int originalSize = stack.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalSize - indexOfToRemove - 1; i++) {
      tempStack.push(stack.pop());
    }
    stack.pop();  //Extra pop to remove the desired element
    System.out.println("Temporary stack: " + tempStack);
    while (!tempStack.empty()) {
      stack.push(tempStack.pop());
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
Original stack: [a, e, b, k, b, c, l]
Temporary stack: [l, c, b, k, b, e]
Modified stack: [e, b, k, b, c, l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Deque. You can add/remove on both sides.
deque.getLast(), deque.getFirst() will give you that what you want.